# rails 3.2 select form helper set readonly true not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble setting readonly => true on a form helper. It still allows me to change the selection. Here is my code.

```
<%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, {:order => [:day, :month, :year]}, {:readonly => true} %>
```

Comment: If you just want the date not editable, why not just use a input-text ?

Comment: The final consensus is to use a hidden field and display the select with a disabled attribute. The hidden field will be submitted to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readonly` option does not exist in the HTML [`<select>`-tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) or [`<otption>`-tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) and even Rails cannot magically add such an option to HTML..!

Instead, you can use `:disabled => true`, to show the select fields as 'disabled':

```
f.date_select :date_of_birth, {:disabled => true, :order => [:day, :month, :year]}
```

Values of disabled fields are not send with the form though, so if this is required, you need to add a copy of the field as [hidden](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) as well.
This hidden field/value is then send with the form, and the disabled field is shown in on your page.

Comment: I tried disabled but then the data does not get submitted with the form :(

Comment: If you cannot modify it, why do you require the data to be submitted?

Comment: I suppose this is A limitation of HTML, not Rails. You _could_ add the value as [hidden](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) as well, so they get send. (I am not saying I really like this method..! ;) )

Comment: In my app, If the user wants to add a student, they submit the name and birth date and the app checks for a possible duplicate. A new form is returned but I don't want to allow modification of the name or birth date but I do want them submitted.

Comment: As said, add them as hidden inputs (and show the values as regular text somewhere)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: This answer is wrong because the value does not get submitted to server. Using readonly does not work with select fields. Consequently, the correct solution is displaying a disabled select field but adding a hidden input field directly underneath with the same name attributes. Mark this down because a lot of solutions offered on stackoverflow, but none of them are fully correct.